# Static methods of a nested local class

Tags: c++, thread-safety, nested-class

My question is an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2372714/368599).

In the original question, the OP asked whether the local variables of a static function need to be protected against data races. The answer was that each thread gets its own stack frame. Is it safe to assume the same applies to nested classes with static functions?

```
// Function called by several threads
int someFunc(int a, int b)
{
  struct nestedStruct
  {
    static int do_something(int& a, int& b)
    {
      a = rand();
      b = rand();
      return a + b;

    }
  };

  return nestedStruct::do_something(a, b);
}
```

Comment: All local variables go on the stack, and all threads get a separate stack. Whether it's a static function or a nested class has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Can nested classes (I mean defined inside a function) have static members at all ? I tried with a static member variable. Didn't work.

Comment: @Sharad: It sure can... http://ideone.com/tl8Za

Comment: Turns out methods are allowed. Variables aren't.
int test8() {
 class F{
   public:
            static int x;
 };
     int F::x = 1;
     return 0;
}

doesn't compile..

Comment: @Sharad: Make sure it is not static (static members are not allowed in a local class). So this will work fine: http://ideone.com/xY9i5

Comment: Hmm I got that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer `someFunc` has its own stack frame, so if `rand` is thread safe (I'm not sure if it is) then both the outer function and nested static function are fine.

Comment: Good point about `rand`, it probably updates a static seed value that isn't protected in any way.

Comment: On VC it's safe, POSIX in general not (see `rand_r`).

Comment: I concur, good point about `rand()` (+1) but that was just a copy/paste from the original question and is not the point of the question.